# Rendering Http result Angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to render an Http call result in the template with no success. 
I am actually able to make the trip all the way back to this.business - but am unable to render it on the view. Am I missing something? Seems to work like magic here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Here is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Business } from './business';
import { BusinessService } from './business.service';
import '/app/rxjs-operators';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-business',
  templateUrl: 'business.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['business.component.css'],
  providers:[BusinessService]
})
export class BusinessComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() business: Business;
  // business: Business;
  errorMessage: string;
  mode = 'Observable';
  constructor(private businessService: BusinessService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getBusiness();
  }

  getBusiness(){
    this.businessService.getBusiness()
      .subscribe(
        function(business){
          this.business = business;
          console.log(this.business); // this outputs correct JSON
        },
        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }
}
```

My Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Business } from './business';

@Injectable()
export class BusinessService {
  businessUrl:'http://localhost:8082/business/1';
  constructor(private http:Http){}

  getBusiness():Observable<Business> {
    console.log('http://localhost:8082/business/1');
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8082/business/1')
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    console.log(body);
    return body || { };
  }

  private handleError(error:any) {
    // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
      error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an arrow function instead of a fat function:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-business',
  templateUrl: 'business.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['business.component.css'],
  providers:[BusinessService]
})
export class BusinessComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() business: Business;
  // business: Business;
  errorMessage: string;
  mode = 'Observable';

  constructor(private businessService: BusinessService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getBusiness();
  }

  getBusiness(){
    this.businessService.getBusiness()
      .subscribe(
        (business) => { // <-------
          this.business = business;
      );
  }
}
```

This way `this` will be the component instance (see lexical this of arrow functions). With a fat function, `this` corresponds to the instance the function is executed on and not the component instance here. So you set the `business` property not on the component instance...

Comment: Ah! So in arrow functions, the this skips belonging to the function itself?

Comment: To the object where the function is called. See this link for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this

Answer (score 1):

According to me everything seems okay. Still go with `()=>something` arrow function as shown below

```
getBusiness(){
    this.businessService.getBusiness()
      .subscribe((business)=>{         //<----added arrow function
          this.business = business;
          console.log(this.business);  
        })
       .(error) => { this.errorMessage = <any>error}
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, @micronyks. Other answerer got in 6 seconds before you, but you both were right :-)